# iterating through dropdown on blur of the dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has date of birth field that is displayed in 3 dropdowns(Month Date Year). I am trying to validate these dropdowns based on the class.
Currently validations are done on id based. Say for example, if there are 5 dob fields, 5 validation functions are there for each of these 5 dob fields based on their
id's. But that is not a good way. So now I am trying to create a common class for all of these dob fields and trying to do the validations.
All the dob fields are not displayed..Some are hidden. Based on certain conditions, they are displayed.
HTML for one dropdown is as given below. Similarly I have the another 5 set as well

```
<div class="dob">  
<select class="dob1" id="dob_month" name="dob_month">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <%=dob_1%>
</select>
<span class="inline-text-dob"></span>

<select  class="dob2" id="dob_date" name="dob_date" >
   <option value="">Day</option>
    <%=dob_2%>
</select>

<span class="inline-text-dob"></span>

<select  class="dob3"  id="dob_year" name="dob_year" title="Please enter valid Date of Birth.">
    <option value="">Year</option>
        <%=dob_3%>
</select>
</div>
```

Now I need to validate each of these date of birth fields on blur of each of the dropdowns and also on submit of the page.. I have the js function for that as well. That function works fine, for single dob field. But when I have more than 1 dob fields, there is some problem with the looping I am writing.
JS function

```
function dobValidation(){
//code

var input1 = $('select.dob1');
var input2 = $('select.dob2');
var input3 = $('select.dob3');

var dob1 = input1.val();
var dob2 = input2.val();
var dob3 = input3.val();
alert("dob1 "+dob1+" dob2 "+dob2+" dob3 "+dob3);//Here it always alerts the first dob field values

//doing other validations like checking month, age etcc

return true/false;
}
```

On blur of each I am doing like this.

```
$('.dob1').each(function(){
    $('.dob1').blur(dobValidation);
});
$('.dob2').each(function(){
    $('.dob2').blur(dobValidation);
});
$('.dob3').each(function(){
    $('.dob3').blur(dobValidation);
});
```

On Sumit of the page, I am doing like this.

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    var returnValue = true;

    var retDOB = dobValidation();
    return returnValue;
});
```

But now I have an issue, if I have selected all the 3 values for the first dob field, when I select the second dob field, it is still alerting the first value.
There seems to be a problem in looping.
Can anyone please guide me in this?

Answer (score 0):

you are calling `dobValidation()` on `blur` of each `select` tag

instead of this:-

```
$('.dob1').each(function(){
    $('.dob1').blur(dobValidation);
});
$('.dob2').each(function(){
    $('.dob2').blur(dobValidation);
});
$('.dob3').each(function(){
    $('.dob3').blur(dobValidation);
});
```

try this:-

```
$('body').not('.dob').click(function () {
  dobValidation()
})

$('.dob').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

**EDIT:-** for validation of every single input create a function say `validateIt()` and call it on blur of that element

```
$('.dob1,.dob2,.dob3').each(function(){

    $(this).blur(function(e)
    {
        validateIt($(this))
    });
});

function validateIt(obj)
{
    alert(obj.val())
    //do something..
}
```

Comment: but i need to validate on blur of each of the dropdown also..so any idea how i can do this when the user changes focus from each dropdown.

Comment: Hi UDB, thanks for the reply..I tried ur answer..bt its not working as expected..jsfiddle.net/jUQYr/61/

Comment: when I first select the value, its not alerting that itself..if u can have a look into the fiddle. u will understand

Comment: @user1049057 i have changed the `blur` callback a little http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/jUQYr/62/ (use console's log to see it working if alert window doesn't appear)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply....I checked it and alerting the values...so from this how can i identify the order of the fields(month, date, year)..Each fields are having different ids also.. is it possible to pass, month, date and year value for each of the dob fields to the dobValidation() function. Only then I can do the validation for each dob field..Hope I dint confuse u..

Comment: @user1049057 use `name` attribute `dob_month, dob_date, dob_year` here an example http://jsfiddle.net/UD_B/jUQYr/66/ to show how to wrap data inside an object using `name` as key/index (in case of object it is called as property) and given `value` as `value for that key`

Comment: Thanks for ur time...I will check this..But i have a query here. In my html, all the dob field's name are different. Eg for month for first dob, it will be dob_month, second dob field it will be don_month1. So since u asked to use name attribute, then there will be too many line of code..That is y I was trying to do class based with common classes for month, date and day..So is it possible for ur solution to use classes? Thanks a lot for looking into this issue..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42174/discussion-between-user1049057-and-udb)